# HTML 5 canvas image special effects

Tags: html, graphics, canvas, 2d, html5-canvas

I'm working on a 2d tile based HTML5 canvas application and I would like to know what kind of special effects I can apply to the images as their being drawn ( context.drawImage(...) ). The only trick I've come across is modifying the canvas.globalAlpha value. This leaves some color from the previous frames, creating a blurring or dazed effect if things on the canvas object are moving from frame to frame.

Is there something for rendering images that is comparable to setting the context.fillStyle to an ARGB value for primitive shapes?

Is there a multiply mode? ie: multiply the image pixel color by the destination color. This could be used for primitive lighting. (I've toyed around with context.globalCompositionOperation but didn't find anything interesting)

Are there any other cool effects you've come across?

NOTE: I don't want to use WebGL for this application, and it's a game. That means it's realtime and I can't modify each pixel with javascript code because that takes too long. (although I could probably do that when the player dies and nothing is moving on the screen anymore)

Answer (score 0):

Canvas doesn't provide any predefined effects. 
To manipulate the image shape you can use matrix transformations.
To manipulate the image pixels and colors you should use getImageData method - http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#pixel-manipulation.
Then use google to find algorithms to apply some effects like swirl, blur, emboss etc.